# Coding arduino traffic ligth with timer and button

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I need make a traffic light that works on countdown:

when number on timer == 0 or if button pressed green led should turn on

otherwise red led

There is my loop,
I tried without for loop and button worked but if I add for loop (for timer) button not responding

thank you

```
  crosswalk_button = digitalRead(2);  //That will read the state of the button, if it's pressed or not 

  for (int i = numberfor7digit; i >= 0; i--) { //numberfor7digit is = 9

    numbers(i); //numbers is a function i wrote which shows int it takes currently i
    delay(1000);

    if (crosswalk_button == 0) { //If you press the button for the crosswalk on with the green one for the crosswalk       
      numbers(0);                     
      greenhigh();                    // green high is a function too, which turns on green light
    }

    // when number in 7 segment is 0 it will turn on green
    else if (i == 0) {
      numbers(0);
      greenhigh();         
    } 

    // for any other number it turns on red
    else {
    digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, LOW);
    }  
  }     
}
```

Comment: Most probably it is not working because you are not taking input for `crosswalk_button` continuously (`digitalRead(2)` only called once before the loop). I don't think your logic is correct. You need a separate handler for the `crosswalk_button`.

Answer (score 1):

Few things which will help you to design this system effectively are:

### Use Interrupts to read the value of the button

1. This will make the turning on Green Light irrespective of what's been executed by the Arduino when the button is pressed.
2. Example: Illustration to show how to configure a button for interrupt

   ```cpp
   int interruptPin = 2; //button attached to this pin
   void setup() {
      pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), greenhigh, LOW);
   }

   void loop() {
      //Your code inside this loop
   }

   void greenhigh() {
      //Your code for turning green light high
      numbers(0);
      digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);
   }
   ```

### Seven Segment Display

1. Now, since the button is fixed writing code for seven segment display will be simpler.
2. Example: Illustration to show SSD working

   ```c
   digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);
   for (int i = numberfor7digit; i >= 0; i--) { 
      numbers(i);
      delay(1000); 
   }
   greenhigh();  
   delay(5000);
   ```

### Conclusion

#### Complete code can be written as:

```c
int interruptPin = 2; //button attached to this pin
int numberfor7digit = 9;
int GREEN_LED = 10; //TODO: Input here your actual green led
int RED_LED = 11; //TODO: Input here your actual red led
void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), greenhigh, LOW);
}

void greenhigh() {
  //TODO: Your code for turning green light high
  numbers(0);
  digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);
}

void numbers(int n) {
  //Your implementaion of numbers()
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);
  for (int i = numberfor7digit; i >= 0; i--) {
    numbers(i);
    delay(1000);
  }
  greenhigh();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the status of your button every time the loop runs i.e. the for loop that you are using.

And I have also removed the `delay` and replaced it with an if statement similar to `blink without delay` example.

One more thing, there is no need to create a `crosswalk_button` variable
You can directly replace it with `digitalRead(2)`

Use this code, it should work.

```
void loop() {
    for(int i = numberfor7digit; ; i >= 0; i--) {
    
    static long previousMillis = 0;
    
        if(millis() - previousMillis >= 1000) {
            numbers(i);
            previousMillis = millis();
        }
    
        crosswalk_button = digitalRead(2);
        
        if(crosswalk_button == false || i == 0) {
            i = 0;
            numbers(i);
            greenhigh();
        } else {
            digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, LOW):
        }
    }
}
```